# A short answer\reply to the negative exclamations with\without tags

Tags: tag-questions

An example from Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*:

> She's growing up to be a lovely person. ~ Yes, **isn't she**!

1. Would it be fine to reply to this with "Yes, she is"? I suppose it would.
2. What's the rule for a short answer\reply to the exclamations\rhetorical questions with tags?

> She's growing to be X, isn't she? ~ **Yes,______?  No,_______?**

Judging on the Swan's example, there are two possible replies in either case - with and without tag, right?

Comment: I don't understand your second question. "She's growing to be X, isn't she?" "Yes, she is." or "No, she's not." seem to be your choices. There's no construction in which "No, [something positive]" would be possible without resorting to hyperbole; e.g., "She's growing up to be a lovely person." "No, she's growing up to be a *fantastic, gorgeous, brilliant, gifted* person!"

Comment: @Mark Hubbard   There's where my problem lies. I'm quite familiar with standard answers "Yes, she is", "No, she isn't". In Swan's example for the first time have I encountered a short affirmative reply with a negation within: "Yes, isn't she!" I've never come across such a construction before.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard  So, there are (at least) two possibilities to reply to a statement "She is X!" - 1) Yes, she is! 2) Yes, isn't she! The form of the latter suggests a tag-question (?) - "She is X, isn't she?" What's a short reply to it? "Yes, isn't she!" - as an echo question/exclamation - sounds odd to me. "Yes, she is!" is standard, but how did Swan's variant come about, then? What's the rule? Is it possible only with affirmative statements, but not with tag-questions?

Comment: In "Yes, isn't she!", *isn't she* isn't really a negation, but is asking for your confirmation. If you agree that "She's growing up to be a lovely person" then *yes*, if not, *no*.

Answer (score 2):

> She's growing up to be a lovely person. ~ Yes, isn't she!

As user3169 has mentioned, "yes, isn't she!" in this case is merely asking for your confirmation. It's the same as saying "Yes, don't you agree?"

So the options for your reply to the literal question are either yes or no.

So to answer your first question, then:

> 1. Would it be fine to reply to this with "Yes, she is"?

Yes, you could reply to that.

---

The answer to the second question is slightly more complicated.

> 2. What's the rule for a short answer\reply to the exclamations\rhetorical questions with tags?

The way these types of phrases are used conversationally is that the person saying "isn't she [lovely]" is not actually asking you for your opinion on her loveliness. Rather, they're implying a "yes" answer for you. In effect, they're *telling you* that she is lovely.

You can see this in the punctuation: there's an exclamation point at the end of the sentence, not a question mark. That's to indicate that, though the phrase is technically a question, it's actually just a statement: *Yes, she's lovely.*

So with that being the default interpretation then, you are left with basically three choices:

1. You can join in on the praise. *"Oh yeah, she always brightens my day!"*
2. You give a quick *"yep"* or even say nothing at all, with your silence implying your agreement.
3. You can disagree. *"Actually, once you get to know her, she's actually really awful."*

Given that the speaker did not *actually* ask for your opinion by saying "isn't she?," replying with anything in the negative is likely to have an extra strong effect. In the case of "Isn't she [lovely]?," replying with any type of "no" answer would be like going out of your way to criticize her, so you could risk coming off as rude.

Because of this, faced with a situation where a native speaker hears one of these questions that basically boils down "don't you agree with me?" when they actually don't agree, many might choose to just keep their mouth shut and not actually voice their disagreement.

Answer (score -2):

She's growing up to be a lovely person. ~ Yes, isn't she!

Wrong, it is not exclamation. It is question tag and you need question mark at the end, not exclamation mark :

She's growing up to be a lovely person. ~ Yes, isn't she?

Comment: Are you going to argue with M.Swan?  _Isn't the weather nice! 
Hasn't she grown!_